# TinyMCE GoogleSpell

Tags: tinymce, sugarcrm

Did Google stopped their Spell Service? It seems that my TinyMCE's spellchecker stopped working using GoogleSpell as the engine. It was working previously and just this week it stopped, when I changed the engine to PSpellShell its working.

The TinyMCE editor is in a SugarCRM installation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the service is down (https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell).
But this has occured several times in the past already.
I'd just wait a bit and see if it gets back online.